# [Angular 10][Rxjs] Why second pipe not firing

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have two subscribers to the same Observable, but the second one not emitting values.
Is there a limitation to pipe which I am lacking knowledge of?

#### component.ts

```js
  private readonly destroyed$ = new Subject<void>();

  public readonly vm$ = this.service.vm$.pipe(
    tap(console.log),
    takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
  );

  public readonly labels$ = this.service.vm$.pipe(
    zip(this.makeLabels),
    tap(console.log),
    takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
  )

  ...
  constructor(private readonly service: SomeService) {
    this.service.load();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroyed$.next();
    this.destroyed$.complete();
  }
```

#### some.service.ts

```
  export class SomeService implements OnDestroy {
    private readonly destroyed$ = new Subject<void>();
    private _vm$ = new BehaviorSubject<ViewModel>(null);
    public readonly vm$ = this._vm$.asObservable().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$));
    ...
    load() { this._vm$.next({...}) }
  }
```

#### component.html

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="vm$ | async as vm">
  <header>
    <pre *ngFor="let label of labels$ | async">
       {{label | json}} 
    </pre>
  </header>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just combine `vm$` and `label$` so that you are piping/subscribing only once? Or is this a general question whether this is even possible?

Comment: What's the actual value you are assigning `_vm$` here: `load() { this._vm$.next({...}) }`?

Comment: It was more like a general question, because this way I can make my working code more readable.

Comment: What is the intention with `zip`, that could be causing your problem of not emitting as expected.

Comment: The observable emits and object where I need to compose a new object. Based on [documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/zip) I think this is the one I should use for this puprose, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to move `*ngFor="let label of labels$ | async"` from `pre` to a higher-order `ng-container`.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="vm$ | async as vm">
  <header>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let label of labels$ | async">
      <pre>
         {{label | json}} 
      </pre>
    </ng-container>
  </header>
</ng-container>
```

I don't know why, but this way it works. Maybe someone can explain it.